# How would I assign the values of 11,12, and 13 to all equal 10 without using logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs in C?

Tags: c, printf, ascii, selection, logical-operators

I'm supposed to make a program that is basically a simple form of Blackjack. The program randomly draws 4 cards from a standard deck of 52, and the card number should be displayed along with its card value. (For example, if the card number is 43 it has a value of 4) The cards 2-10 are worth their given value, an Ace is worth 1, the face cards (11-13, jack, queen, king) are worth 10. When the total exceeds 21 the program should display a 'B' after the total. I'm having trouble with the last two parts. I can't figure out how to get the face cards to equal 10, and to display a 'B' without using logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs such as an if statement. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! 
Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int seedValue();
int card();
int cardValue(int);
int cardValue2(int);
int cardValue3(int);
int cardValue4(int);
void printStatements(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
  int seed;
  int cardnum1;
  int cardnum2;
  int cardnum3;
  int cardnum4;
  int value1;
  int value2;
  int value3;
  int value4;

  seed = seedValue();

  srand(seed);

  cardnum1 = card();
  cardnum2 = card();
  cardnum3 = card();
  cardnum4 = card();

  value1 = cardValue(cardnum1);
  value2 = cardValue2(cardnum2);
  value3 = cardValue3(cardnum3);
  value4 = cardValue4(cardnum4);

  printStatements(cardnum1,cardnum2,cardnum3,cardnum4,value1,value2,value3,value4);

  return(0);
}

int seedValue()
{
  int seed;

  printf("Enter the seed value: ");
  scanf("%d",&seed);

  return(seed);
}

int card()
{
  int cardval;

  cardval = (rand() % 52) + 1;

  return(cardval);
}

int cardValue(int cardnum1)
{
  int val1;


  val1 = cardnum1 % 13;

  return(val1);
}

int cardValue2(int cardnum2)
{
  int val2;

  val2 = cardnum2 % 13;

  return(val2);
}

int cardValue3(int cardnum3)
{
  int val3;

  val3 = cardnum3 % 13;

  return(val3);
}

int cardValue4(int cardnum4)
{
  int val4;

  val4 = cardnum4 % 13;

  return(val4);
}

void printStatements(int cardnum1, int cardnum2, int cardnum3, int cardnum4, int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4)
{
  printf("1. Card generated: %d Card value: %d\n",cardnum1,value1);
  printf("2. Card generated: %d Card value: %d\n",cardnum2,value2);
  printf("3. Card generated: %d Card value: %d\n",cardnum3,value3);
  printf("4. Card generated: %d Card value: %d\n",cardnum4,value4);

  printf("Total points generated is: %d\n",value1 + value2 + value3 + value4);
}
```

Comment: *"without using logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs such as an if statement"* Why not use those? If this is an assignment and that's a restriction on the assignment, look at your recent classwork, and it should point fairly clearly to what to use.

Comment: An array of 13 integers, containing the card value?

Comment: When you have variables like `cardnum1`, `cardnum2`, `cardnum3`, `cardnum4`, you almost certainly want an array: `int cardnum[4]`.

Comment: And why do you have four functions doing the exact same thing? You could call one of them with different arguments instead.

Comment: Curious to know why would someone wants to do all that ?

Comment: i'm really new to programming so all of what looks obvious to you doesn't look that way to me at all. It is for an assignment. And we haven't learned about arrays or if statements so that's why I have to write everything out instead of using something simpler. Sorry I should have mentioned that. Thanks for whatever useful input you can offer

Comment: Well, this might be a good time to learn.  If the instructor is making you play “Mother, may I?” then you should ask what you are allowed to do.

Comment: @CatherineFoye There is nothing syntactically wrong with the way you have written it, it is just a bit longer than you will write it a month from now. As to your question, after you set the values of your cards, just test `if (cardnum1 >= 10) cardnum1 = 10;` (and the same for the rest) Yes, there are much shorter ways to right that as well, but you will get to them in time. (Ok, I'll give you a hint, the `ternary` operator)

Comment: Try something like `val - (val % 10)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still being unclear lol. I know how to use arrays, logic and relations, and if statements. We just aren't allowed to use them right now for this. That's why I asked for it specifically without using any of those. There's nothing wrong with the current code, I just have no idea what to add to it to give the card numbers 11,12, 13 a value of 10, or how to add "B" to the print statement if the total is over 21. I've looked through class notes, the C programming book, and my teammates are useless so I'm on my own. Again thanks to anyone that answers

Comment: Thank you @Ôrel I will try that

Comment: Obviously your teacher is looking for this solution: `val=(val&??-7&&val-2&??-7)*012;`. I seriously think that you should hand in this solution and thank them for making you such a great C programmer.

Comment: the functions `cardValue` and `cardValue2`, `cardValue3`, `cardValue4` are all the same, why declare separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, there was nothing wrong with the syntax used in writing your program, it is just quite a bit longer than you will write it a month from now. Taking the suggestions and making use of a couple of arrays will help you dramatically cut down on the verbosity of the code while still retaining all the information you desired to print.

In the same manner, reducing the number of functions that provide the same logic also helps to cut down on the line in the code (bad if you are getting paid by the line...)

To your question of keeping card values equal to 10 for all face cards, that can be handled in your `cardValue` function with a simple test after you reduce the value to between `1 - 13`. A simple `if (value >= 10) value = 10;` will insure all face cards have the value of 10.

With those changes made, while still lengthy, it is a bit shorter than the original. Give it a try and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SUITS 4

int seedValue();
int card();
int cardValue(int);
void printDeal (int *cards, int *values);

int main()
{
    int cardnum[SUITS] = {0};
    int cardval[SUITS] = {0};
    int i = SUITS;

    srand (seedValue());

    while (i--) {
        cardnum[i] = card();
        cardval[i] = cardValue (cardnum[i]);
    }

    printDeal (cardnum, cardval);

    return 0;
}

int seedValue()
{
    int seed;

    printf ("Enter the seed value: ");
    scanf ("%d",&seed);

    return seed;
}

int card ()
{   return (rand() % 52) + 1; }

int cardValue (int cardnum)
{
    int val = cardnum % 13;

    return val > 10 ? 10 : val;
}

void printDeal (int *cards, int *values)
{
    int i, pts = 0;

    putchar ('\n');  /* just to make it look nice */

    for (i = 0; i < SUITS; i++) {
        printf (" Card[%2d] : generated: %2d  value: %2d\n",
                i + 1, cards[i], values[i]);
        pts += values[i];
    }
    printf ("\nTotal points generated : %d\n\n", pts);
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cards
Enter the seed value: 21

 Card[ 1] : generated: 11  value: 10
 Card[ 2] : generated:  3  value:  3
 Card[ 3] : generated: 52  value:  0
 Card[ 4] : generated: 17  value:  4

Total points generated : 17
```

Answer (score -1):

if you can use %

```
val - val % 10
```